# pandas: taking the diff of every second row

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
                       price    signal
time                    
2017-10-28 13:54:00   293.18    buy
2017-11-02 17:13:04   285.30    sell
2017-11-02 18:40:04   283.24    buy
2017-11-03 08:40:06   291.23    sell
2017-11-03 12:38:06   294.26    buy
2017-11-05 13:33:06   296.52    sell
```

I want to create a profit column populated with the difference of the previous buy/sell pair

```
                       price    signal   profit
time                    
2017-10-28 13:54:00   293.18    buy
2017-11-02 17:13:04   285.30    sell     -7.88
2017-11-02 18:40:04   283.24    buy
2017-11-03 08:40:06   291.23    sell      7.99
2017-11-03 12:38:06   294.26    buy
2017-11-05 13:33:06   296.52    sell      2.29
```

How might I best go about this?
Alternative or more efficient approaches to calculating profit also welcome

Comment: df.groupby(df.signal.eq('buy').cumsum())['price'].diff()

Comment: @WeNYoBen that worked perfectly, thank you

Comment: If truly every 2 rows can just `df['profit'] = df.price.diff()[1::2]`. But rather unsafe

Comment: @WeNYoBen Maybe post that as an answer for future reference?

Comment: @run-out ok :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC using `cumsum` create the group key , then `diff`

```
df.groupby(df.signal.eq('buy').cumsum())['price'].diff()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do:

```
    df['profit'] = df.price - df.price.shift()
```

Do you always close out your position before taking another though?

I would suggest a trade_id column, to use to marry up trades.